# perl Regex replace for specific string length

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am using Perl to do some prototyping.

I need an expression to replace `e` by `[ee]` if the string is exactly 2 chars and finishes by "e".

```
le -> l [ee]
me -> m [ee]
elle -> elle : no change
```

I cannot test the length of the string, I need one expression to do the whole job.

I tried:

```
`s/(?=^.{0,2}\z).*e\z%/[ee]/g`  but this is replacing the whole string
`s/^[c|d|j|l|m|n|s|t]e$/[ee]/g` same result (I listed the possible letters that could precede my "e")
`^(?<=[c|d|j|l|m|n|s|t])e$/[ee]/g` but I have no match, not sure I can use ^ on a positive look behind
```

**EDIT**
Guys you're amazing, hours of search on the web and here I get answers minutes after I posted.

I tried all your solutions and they are working perfectly directly in my script, i.e. this one:

```
 my $test2="le";
 $test2=~ s/^(\S)e$/\1\[ee\]/g;
 print "test2:".$test2."\n";
 -> test2:l[ee]
```

But I am loading these regex from a text file (using Perl for proto, the idea is to reuse it with any language implementing regex):

In the text file I store for example (I used % to split the line between match and replace):

```
 ^(\S)e$% \1\[ee\]
```

and then I parse and apply all regex like that:

```
my $test="le";
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    if( $row =~ /%/){
        my @reg = split /%/, $row;
        #if no replacement, put empty string
        if($#reg == 0){
            push(@reg,"");
        }
        print "reg found, reg:".$reg[0].", replace:".$reg[1]."\n";
        push @regs, [ @reg ];
    }
}
print "orgine:".$test."\n";
for my $i (0 .. $#regs){
    my $p=$regs[$i][0];
    my $r=$regs[$i][1];
    $test=~ s/$p/$r/g;
}
print "final:".$test."\n";
```

This technique is working well with my other regex, but not yet when I have a $1 or \1 in the replace... here is what I am obtaining:

```
final:\1\ee\
```

PS: you answered to initial question, should I open another post ?

Comment: What is the allowable first character, anything ?

Comment: All assertions operate at the current position. They look ahead or behind. Since `^` matched, the current position is 0, BOS, there is nothing before there.

Comment: `This technique is working well with my other regex, but not yet when I have a $1 or \1 in the replace` - The regex is just replacing what's in `$r`. I think you have to go one step further using the `s///e` evaluation form  (see the _perlre_ docs) for the replacement. The regex  would then look like `$test=~ s/$p/$r/e;`.

Comment: `/e` didn't work, but instead I used `my $evalRX = '$test3=~ s/'.$p.'/'.$r.'/g';
    eval $evalRX;` which is ok for prototyping..

Comment: Yep, a double eval. I don't know how you get it to recognize `\1` in an eval as anything other than the character - decimal 1. Anyway, you can do the same thing with this. Just do the quoting in the file (i.e. `^(\S)e$% " ${1}[ee]"` ) Anytime you do quoting, remember to isolate the capture group vars if right next to an array element literal.  Here is a test case. `my $test = 'le'; my ($p,$r) = split /%/, '^(\S)e$% " ${1}[ee]"'; $test =~ s/$p/$r/ee; print $test;`

Answer (score 2):

Something like `s/(?i)^([a-z])e$/$1[ee]/`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\S)e$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1 [ee]`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/28

Comment: Juvenile's here downvoting. +1 best answer!

Comment: @sln  I upvoted vks's and sln's because they match the requested specification. I have an answer below that is similar that was downvoted without any feedback...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex which match 2 character and then you can replace it with `$1\[$2$2\]`:

```
^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])$
```

Demo :

```
$my_string =~ s/^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])$/$1[$2$2]/;
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/iD9oN4/1

Comment: You forgot the first capturing group in your second code snippet. Also, you don't need to backslash-escape braces on the RHS of the substitution, and the OP only wanted to match strings ending in `e`, not strings ending in any letter.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks, I just gave a general solution!

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a capture group to do the replacement?

```
`s/^([c|d|j|l|m|n|s|t])e$/\1 [ee]/g`
```

If those are the characters you need and if it is indeed one word to a line with no whitespace before it or after it, then this will work.

Here's another option depending on what you are looking for. It will match a two character string consisting of one a-z character followed by one 'e' on its own line with possible whitespace before or after. It will replace this will the single a-z character followed by ' [ee]'

```
`s/^\s*([a-z])e\s*$/\1 [ee]/`
```

Comment: You need to explain why you are downvoting if you want people to help you.

Comment: The first regex doesn't really need those alternations in the class. Or is implicit in classes. The second regex is a good generalized one, allowing for formatting. +1.

Comment: `[a|b]` matches `a`, `b`, and a vertical bar; you should use `[ab]` if you don't want to match literal `|`s. Also, [you should use `$1` instead of `\1`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this

```
$word =~ s/^(\w{1})(e)$/$1$2e/;
```

Comment: or simplified to  $word =~ s/^(\w[e])$/$1e/;

Comment: Hello, `\w{1})` == `\w`. And, really no need to capture the _e_, its a constant.

Comment: yea, that's why I simplified it.